# Is there a macro recorder in Xamarin studio?

Tags: ide, code-editor, xamarin-studio

I can't find the keystroke macro recorder in Xamarin Studio, however it's an usefull feature for an IDE (to edit some aligned code lines for example). Where is it hidden ?

In the same order of idea, searches are bit basic, where can I set if a search is only related to the "full words" (so the expression separated by symbols/blanks) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of March 6th, 2013, it appears there is no keystroke macro support
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1987/keystroke-macros-please

The post talks about code snippets, maybe that will work for you?

Martin

Comment: no I'm looking for a recorder for pattern such as ARROW DOWN, CTRL+RIGHT, BACKSPACE repeated for x times